# When do I use the self property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, swift

I am trying to better grasp the use of `self`. Is using `self` basically just a shortcut to typing out the class name? For example, in the code below, if I use `self` does it refer to the `Tank2` class? For example, is it basically a shortcut to typing out `Tank2.bonusDamage`? I don't understand what "the current instance" is that self is referring to.

I don't quite grasp it because I notice for example that these top two code snippets return the exact same thing.

```
    //SNIPPET 1:
    var damage: Double {
    return baseDamage + Tank2.bonusDamage  
}

    //SNIPPET 2:
    var damage: Double {
    return self.baseDamage + Tank2.bonusDamage

}
```

.

```
class Tank2 {
class var bonusDamage: Double {
    return Double(Upgrade.level) * 2.5
}

let baseDamage = 10.0

var damage: Double {
    return baseDamage + Tank2.bonusDamage
}

class func upgrade() {
    Upgrade.level += 1

}

struct Upgrade{
static var level = 0
}
}
```

Comment: `self` is used to call the defined property of the class using `@property annotation` in the interface, however you can access the property by adding `_` prefix too, or, if its a static property you can access it by Classname, not `self`. Other than that, any thing declared can be accessed `without self`. And if you synthesize your property to class, then again you don't need `self` to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class definition  describes the properties and methods of the class like the plans for a car describe its size, number of seats and so on - but you can't drive  plans, you need an actual instance of a car built from those plans.

Similarly with an object class - you need an actual instance of a class to operate on.

Given a simple Car class -

```
Class Car
   property color:Color
   property fuelTankLevel:Integer
   propert (readOnly) capacity:Integer = 60 // Fuel tank capacity in litres
```

Note that this isn't Swift or Objective C, just a simplified version of  a class.

I could store instances in variables -

```
 let redCar=Car(color:Red)
 let blueCar=Car(color:Blue)
```

which is fine for referring to those cars from within my program, but what about a method of car that let me fill the fuel tank.  From my program I can say `blueCar.fill()` - but inside the `fill` method I need to operate on the right tank.  Inside `fill` I can't refer to `blueCar` and `redCar` because these are just instances outside of the class definition.  This is where `self` comes in.

`self` means "the current object instance", so the `fill` method could be

```
fill() {
    self.fuelTankLevel=self.capacity
}
```

So when this code is *invoked* on an object instance, `self` will be that instance. So when I say `blueCar.fill()` the code that is executed is effectively `blueCar.fuelTankLevel=blueCar.capacity`.

In Swift you can omit `self` and in Objective-C you can use `_fuelTank` (or whatever backing variable you @synthesized) to access the property backing variable directly, but it is a good idea to get into the habit of using `self` as it makes it clear that you are accessing a property and not a local or global variable.  Also in Objective-C it ensures that any setter/getter methods are invoked.

You can define *Class methods* - these are methods that do not operate on any particular instance.  In Objective-C you often see "constructor" class methods that wrap the two-stage alloc/init into a single Class method so instead of saying:

```
 Car *redCar=[[Car alloc]initWithColor:red];
```

You can say

```
 Car *redCar=[Car carWithColor:red];
```

Comment: @ Paulw11 - thank you for your answer, but I still don't understand. In the example I gave, what does using 'self' in this case reference?   'var damage: Double {
    return self.baseDamage + Tank2.bonusDamage}' - Additionally, in the example you gave, what is the current object instance when you use self in the 'fill' method? Is it 'fill()'? Are you basically saying 'fill.fuelTankLevel = fill.capacity'?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain what happens when `fill` is invoked on an instance. In your case you are combining an instance method (code that operates on a particular instance) with a class method - code that is invoked against the class. The `bonusDamage` amount is the same for all Tanks but the baseDamage for a particular tank instance could be changed when the tank is initialised

Answer (score 0):

No `self` is not same as typing a class name.

`self` is a object of current class. So all the properties and functions values which are available in that class can be references using `self`.

However, there are functions (called Class functions and distinguised with `+`), that are not dependent on a class object. These Class Functions are called via class name.
Example

```
Class TestClass
+ (int)addToFive:(int)input
{
   return input+5;
}
```

Call this method [TestClass addToFive:10], will return 15.

```
Class TestClass
@property int counter;

-(int)addToCounter:(int)input
{
   // self.counter corresponds to counter value for self (this particular TestClass object)
   return self.counter + input;
}

// call this method
TestClass *classObject = [TestClass alloc] init];
classObject.counter = 10;
[classObject addToCounter:10] // will return 20.
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In class code - such as a class method, a static method, or the initializer of a class property - `self` means "this class, whatever it may be".

In instance code - such as an instance method, or the initializer of an instance property - `self` means "this instance, whatever it may be".

But in most situations, `self` can be omitted - because if a message is a sent without a recipient, Swift will *assume* that you intend to send it to `self`.

In your example, `baseDamage` is an instance variable, and the phrase `return self.baseDamage + ...` appears in instance code. Thus, you can say `baseDamage` or `self.baseDamage` interchangeably, because Swift assumes that the bare message `baseDamage` *means* `self.baseDamage`.

Comment: And see my Swift tutorial: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html#_self, http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_object_type_declarations_and_features.